# all files necessary to change hostname (FQDN)?

Tags: networking, 16.04, server, hostname, hosts

Per [an older answer](https://serverfault.com/a/331942/132080), these are **all** the files necessary to change the hostname?

- /etc/host.conf
- /etc/hosts
- /etc/hostname
- /etc/sysctl.conf

for Ubuntu 16.04 server LTS on Amazon EC2

Answer (score 1):

There is also

```
sudo hostnamectl
cat /etc/mailname
```

If cloud-init is installed you also need to change

```
/etc/cloud/clound.cfg
```

Set `preserve_hostname: true`

Consider also to change machine-id and ssh-key.